# How to make a promise based function to be executed a few times with setTimeout before giving up in node 6 (i.e. no javascript specs for async/await)

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, settimeout, azure-functions

I need to retrieve the actual value from a promise based function in a node 6 environment (Azure Functions), so I used `co` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) via generators (instead of the async/await paradigm) to handle the inner promise.

I need also to retry a few times that `co`/promise function using `setTimeout` before giving up definitively.

I am currently not able to make the following code work as expected. I am not sure where is the problem, but I can not "yield from the promise returned by `co`", so in the end the array that is passed around the recursive levels of the stack contains promises of values (1/0) rather than the actual values.

This is **the wrapper for the "promise based function"** that is handled with a **try/catch** to make sure we actually **always return either 1 or 0**.

```
const wannabeSyncFunc = () => {
  console.log("outside co...");
  return co(function *(){
    console.log("inside co...");
    try {
      console.log("yielding...");
      // promise that could be rejected hence try/catch
      //
      // I can not change this returned promise, so I must treat it
      // as a promise that could potentially be rejected
      let stuff = yield Promise.resolve();
      console.log("stuff?", stuff);
      console.log("returning 1");
      return 1;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("returning 0");
      return 0;
    }
    console.log("after try/catch...");
  });
}
```

This is the recursive/settimeout function that is supposed to try a few times before giving up.

```
const retryIntervalInMillis = 50;

const wannabeRecursiveFunc = (currTimes, attemptsArray) => {
  return co(function *(){
    console.log("Curr attemptsArray:", attemptsArray);
    console.log("Curr attemptsArray[attemptsArray.length - 1]:", attemptsArray[attemptsArray.length - 1]);
    console.log("Curr Promise.resolve(attemptsArray[attemptsArray.length - 1]):", Promise.resolve(attemptsArray[attemptsArray.length - 1]));
    if (attemptsArray[attemptsArray.length - 1] == Promise.resolve(1)) {
      console.log("Found the solution, returning straight away!")
      return attemptsArray;
    }

    if (currTimes <= 0) {
      console.log("Expired acquiring recursion");
      return attemptsArray;
    }

    currTimes--;
    const currValue = wannabeSyncFunc();
    console.log(`First: currTimes: ${currTimes} currValue: ${currValue} curr attemptsArray: ${attemptsArray}`);
    attemptsArray.push(currValue);
    if (currValue === 1) {
      return attemptsArray;
    }
    console.log(`Then: currTimes: ${currTimes} curr attemptsArray: ${attemptsArray}`);
    return yield setTimeout(wannabeRecursiveFunc, currTimes*retryIntervalInMillis, currTimes, attemptsArray);
    // return Promise.all(attemptsArray);
  });
}
```

I've tried to invoke this in a few different ways like:

```
const numberOfAttempts = 3;
let theArray = wannabeRecursiveFunc(numberOfAttempts, []);
console.log(">>>", theArray);
```

Or assuming `wannabeRecursiveFunc` to return a promise and `.then` after the promise trying to print `theArray`.

I keep seeing inside the array these elements `Promise { 1 }` when printing it, but I would like to see either 1 or 0, so **I hope those checks before the recursion could work as expected**. At the moment those check don't work I think because I am comparing `Promise { 1 }` with `1`.

However, I am not sure this is the reason why the whole thing is not working, and I am not even sure how to fix this. I am not sure whether `co` is needed (even in the node.js v6 environment), and how to make this promise/setTimeout work as expected.

Comment: Why do you state "no async-await" but at the same time tag your question with [tag:async-await]?!

Comment: You should  `yield` a promise. `setTimeout` does not return a promise, you need to promisify it first.

Comment: Why are you even using `co` when you do it recursively anyway? Using promise `then` syntax` would lead to a much cleaner solution there.

Comment: @Bergi afaik the `co` library is supposed to mime the async/await pattern for versions of node.js prior to 8, so because I am using `co` then I tagged the question like that. Regarding `yield`-ing the `setTimeout`, yes I am working on that and trying to isolate a minimum working example. Regarding the `co` removal, yes I also think is not strictly necessary, but I am struggling to write a cleaner example that does not involve `co`.

Comment: I don't get why people downvote in what seems to be a random way without giving feedback on what's wrong with the question. I don't see any issue with the question, I put as much effort as I can in explaining what's the problem and part of the problem is that I don't understand some fundamentals of the technology. To be honest: I don't see how this question could be better asked and I thought this website's purpose was to ask questions to get back knowledge and experience otherwise hard to get from documentation and open source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your objective: invoke a function that might fail, if it fails, wait a little bit and retry it.  Do all of that with promises.

Here's a couple tools:

1. a promisified version of setTimeout...

```js
function timeoutPromise(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

timeoutPromise(1000).then(() => {
    console.log('time out expired');
});
```

2. A promise-returning dummy function that sometimes fails...

```js
function fnThatMightFail() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fail = Math.random() < 0.40;
        (fail)? reject('bad') : resolve('good');
    });
}

fnThatMightFail().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And then, I think here's the recursive idea you're looking for.  Pass in a function and a wait time between attempts, call recursively until we succeed...

```js
function fnThatMightFail() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let fail = Math.random() < 0.40;
        (fail)? reject('bad') : resolve('good');
    });
}

function timeoutPromise(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
    });
}

function fnRetryer(fn, tries, wait) {
    if (tries <= 0) return Promise.reject('bad');
    console.log('attempting fn');
    return fn().then(result => {
        console.log(`success: ${result}`);
        return result;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(`error: ${error}, retrying after ${wait}ms`);
        return timeoutPromise(wait).then(result => {
            console.log(`${wait}ms elapsed, recursing...`);
            return fnRetryer(fn, tries-1, wait);
        });
    });
}

fnRetryer(fnThatMightFail, 5, 1000).then(result => {
    console.log(`we tried (and maybe tried) and got ${result}`);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('we failed after 5 tries, waiting 1s in between each try');
});
```

Note that you could add a parameter for a max number of attempts, decrement that on each recursive call and then don't recurse if that gets to zero.  Also note, on the recursive call, you might opt to lengthen the wait time.

Comment: Many thanks, I've reached to the point of a working solution that is similar to yours, however I've incorporated the equivalent of your promise-d `fnThatMightFail` inside the `setTimeout` call, but it looks it effectively does the same thing. I am also decreasing a counter to reach the "basic recursive state" to block the recursion after a bit.

Comment: @TPPZ Promisifying `setTimeout` on its own is much cleaner. This way you will be able catch exceptions from inside the `then` callback.